# Counting noncrossing pairings

Tags: combinatorics, c-star-algebras, random-matrices

I am looking at [Bandeira–Boedihardjo–van Handel](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.06312.pdf)'s definition of a free semicircular family, on p.24. Right below, they claim that
$$\lvert NC_2(p)\rvert=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-2}^2x^p\sqrt{4-x^2}dx$$
for even $p$. Why is this the case? I don't see how moments of this distribution should connect to this counting problem.

It seems that these are just the Catalan numbers (Mathematica agrees on the first several; [Wikipedia claims it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncrossing_partition), though I can't tell if their $NC$ is the same as [BBvH]'s $NC_2$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Banica's Free Probability text [here](http://banica.u-cergy.fr/).

Consult Theorem 7.8 and Proposition 7.26.

I think Banica defines Catalan numbers thus, but then shows they satisfy the usual recurrence.